# Get/assign value from its available range

Tags: r

Looking for some advice.

I have a df with Name and Value's. And with adding addtional Name's to the df should get/assigned next available value within its range.

Each name has range 1 to 5 values.
eg.

```
Name    used        available
A       1,3,5       2,4
B       2,3         1,4,5
C       1,2,3,4,5   None
```

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Value = c(1,3,5,2,3,1,2,3,4,5))

Name    Value
A   1
A   3
A   5
B   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
C   3
C   4
C   5
```

Based on the additional Name as input by the used,
Desired Output on Value Column (should get available unassigned values)

```
Name    Value
A   2
B   1
B   4
C   None
```

Comment: I don't understand why `B` gets two rows in your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution.  This depends upon my assumption that your desired output was as described (you want all other available options) and the depiction at the end was incorrect.  Else, please be more clear when describing your intended output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarize(Value = toString(which(!(1:5 %in% Value)))) %>% 
  separate_rows(Value) %>% 
  mutate(Value = as.numeric(Value))

# A tibble: 6 × 2
    Name Value
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A     2
2      A     4
3      B     1
4      B     4
5      B     5
6      C    NA
```